# XMPP Framework code in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, iphone, xmppframework

I'm working on implementing XMPP framework https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework in my app,i understand there will be a lot of code "methods/delegates" from XMPPRoom, XMPPIQ, XMPPStream etc.. i need to know what's the best place to write all these code, is AppDelegate the best candidate for XMPP related code?

Comment: It's not the same question, but it might be useful read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952017/is-putting-variables-in-the-appdelegate-a-workaround-for-static-variable-in-swif

Comment: It will be better to add XMPP delegates in AppDelegate, since any of them can get triggered from any where from your application. It will be difficult to handle all these delegates in each and every class.

Answer (score 1):

A good practice could be to create a XMPP singleton class. So , you can use all the public methods, properties... within other classes only calling the shared instance.