# Is putting variables in the AppDelegate a workaround for static variable in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, static

Since Swift has no static variables and I'm trying to access a connection, that should be static... is placing this variable in the App Delegate a reasonable solution?

I found this snippet on [GitHub](https://github.com/nemesit/SwiftXMPP/blob/master/SwiftXMPP/ChatViewController.swift):

```
func xmppStream () -> XMPPStream {
    return appDelegate().xmppStream!
}
```

So when `xmppStream()` is called in code, does that return the original instance, or what is actually being done here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't entirely accurate. Swift CLASSES don't have static variables, but structs and enums do!

```
struct Static {
    static var stream: XMPPStream?
}
```

And you can initialize it later in your code if you'd like.

```
Static.stream = XMPPStream()
```

Another approach if you need static variables for a class is to nest a struct inside:

```
class RegularClass {

    struct Static {
        static var stream: XMPPStream?
    }

    //Other code
}
```

And elsewhere you can access it like...

```
RegularClass.Static.stream ...
```

This is probably the best approach currently for Singletons in Swift. Not that I'm fully condoning that.

Comment: Is that what they are doing in the link?

Comment: Nope. I think that code was meant to be a barebones display of how to integrate the framework, not really to be a best-pratice example. Using the app delegate as a global reference to stick stuff is yucky.

Comment: Okay thank-you. I understand the concept now, just trying to understand the structure. So I make a seperate file called `Static.swift` and put my static variable there. Then I can initialize it and access it anywhere as `Static.stream`, am I correct?

Comment: You could do that, yep. Another approach (well, workaround is perhaps the better term until they add static class variables) is to create a struct nested inside the class. I will add that example in my answer.